# Setting SSL or TLS security on NSStream

Tags: objective-c, networking, ssl, nsstream

I have a networking code that uses NSStream, and I want to add security. I tried to apply [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/SecureNetworking/SecureNetworking.html) on the subject. I added the following lines to my working networking code:

```
[input setValue:NSStreamSocketSecurityLevelNegotiatedSSL forKey:NSStreamSocketSecurityLevelKey];
[output setValue:NSStreamSocketSecurityLevelNegotiatedSSL forKey:NSStreamSocketSecurityLevelKey];
```

The initialization code is:

```
-(Connection*) initWithInput:(NSInputStream*) input Output:(NSOutputStream*) output Delegate: (id <ConnectionDelegate>) delegate{
self = [super init];
if (self) {

    a_delegate=delegate;

    //set security
    [input setValue:NSStreamSocketSecurityLevelNegotiatedSSL forKey:NSStreamSocketSecurityLevelKey];
    [output setValue:NSStreamSocketSecurityLevelNegotiatedSSL forKey:NSStreamSocketSecurityLevelKey];

    a_input=input;
    a_output=output;

    //Set delegate to self
    [a_input setDelegate:self];
    [a_output setDelegate:self];

    //Schedule in run loop
    [a_input scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [a_output scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

    //open streams
    [a_input open];
    [a_output open];

}
return self;
}
```

But when my Connection object is initialized, I get an error message and the networking doesn't work:

```
[<__NSCFInputStream 0x60800028e970> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]:
this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key kCFStreamPropertySocketSecurityLevel.
```

Is there anything I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok I found the issue, I should use setProperty:forKey: instead of setValue:forKey: